# HDF5 attributes: Strings are only one character long

Tags: c, string, hdf5

I am writing code to produce HDFs, and I'm having a problem with attributes.  These attributes are all variable length strings, read in from a text file, but I'm capping them quite generously at 256 characters.

My code compiles and runs with no errors.  When I open the file in HDFView, the attributes all have the correct names, but only the first character in the string shows up.

I have started to code for accepting attributes as either single strings, or arrays of strings.  I haven't finished that part, so right now it doesn't do anything with the string arrays.

Here is the input file:

```
year 2013
julian_date 23
start_time_utc 13:54:03
end_time_utc 14:32:05
pixels_per_degree 1000
latitude_corners 34.988644 35.503284 35.960529 36.364529
longitude_corners -119.571877 -118.467979 -120.158424 -119.004395
```

And here is the code snippet:

```
#define FIELDSTRINGLENGTH 256

/*...*/

while(fgets(line, ATTRSTRINGLENGTH, topattributefile)!=NULL) {
  //parse line into individual words                                                                                                                                         
  field=strtok(line," \n");
  strncpy(attributename, field, FIELDSTRINGLENGTH);
  numfields=0;
  field=strtok(NULL," \n");
  while(field!=NULL) {
    strncpy(attributevalue[numfields++], field, FIELDSTRINGLENGTH);
    field=strtok(NULL," \n");
  }
  if(numfields==0) {printf("ERROR: Attribute %s had no value; skipping\n", attributename);}
  else if(numfields>1) {
    if(verboseflag) {printf("Making array of %d attributes with name %s:\n",
                            numfields, attributename);}
    for(i=0;i<numfields;i++) {
      if(verboseflag) {printf("\t%d: %s\n", i, attributevalue[i]);}
    }
  }
  else {
    printf("Making single attribute: %s: %s\n",
                            attributename, attributevalue[0]);}
    //make single attribute                                                                                                                                                  
    attrdataspaceid = H5Screate(H5S_SCALAR);
    attrdatatypeid = H5Tcopy(H5T_C_S1);
    status = H5Tset_size(attrdatatypeid, FIELDSTRINGLENGTH);
    status = H5Tset_strpad(attrdatatypeid, H5T_STR_NULLTERM);
    attributeid = H5Acreate2(fileid, attributename, attrdatatypeid, attrdataspaceid, H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT);
    status = H5Awrite(attributeid, H5T_C_S1, attributevalue[0]);
  }
}
```

Here is the stdout of the relevant snippet:

```
Making top level attributes...
Making single attribute: year: 2013
Making single attribute: julian_date: 23
Making single attribute: start_time_utc: 13:54:03
Making single attribute: end_time_utc: 14:32:05
Making single attribute: pixels_per_degree: 1000
Making array of 4 attributes with name latitude_corners:
    0: 34.988644
    1: 35.503284
    2: 35.960529
    3: 36.364529
Making array of 4 attributes with name longitude_corners:
    0: -119.571877
    1: -118.467979
    2: -120.158424
    3: -119.004395
Finished making top level attributes.
```

Finally, here is the metadata of the HDF as read in HDFView.

```
XXXX.XXXXXX.XXXXXX.hdf (0)
    Group size = 1
    Number of attributes = 5
        year = 2
        julian_date = 2
        start_time_utc = 1
        end_time_utc = 1
        pixels_per_degree = 1
```

Anything strike you as odd here?

Comment: Isnt the space the space you request the problem? `attrdataspaceid = H5Screate(H5S_SCALAR);` this line I mean. I think it should be `H5T_C_S1` as well. Not sure though.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in your call to `H5Awrite()`.

```
status = H5Awrite(attributeid, H5T_C_S1, attributevalue[0]);
```

This is writing only a single character. As the definition of `H5T_C_S1` is

> One-byte, null-terminated string of eight-bit characters.

I normally create a derived type and set it's size. Then call `H5Awrite` with this type, as the write calls copies the size of this in memory type.

Here's a simple example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <hdf5.h>

#define FILENAME "att_str.h5"

int main(){

        hid_t    fid;
        hid_t    att;
        hid_t    ds;
        hid_t    type;
        herr_t   status;
        char     x[] = "lah lah lah";
        int32_t  len = 0;

        fid     = H5Fcreate(FILENAME, H5F_ACC_TRUNC, H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT);
        type    = H5Tcopy(H5T_C_S1);
        len     = strlen(x);
        status  = H5Tset_size(type, len);
        ds      = H5Screate(H5S_SCALAR);
        att     = H5Acreate(fid, "test", type, ds, H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT);
        status  = H5Awrite(att, type, &x);

        status  = H5Aclose(att);
        status  = H5Tclose(type);
        status  = H5Sclose(ds);
        status  = H5Fclose(fid);

        return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Once it is compiled and run the generated file contains:

```
HDF5 "att_str.h5" {
GROUP "/" {
   ATTRIBUTE "test" {
      DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
         STRSIZE 11;
         STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
         CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
         CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
      }
      DATASPACE  SCALAR
      DATA {
      (0): "lah lah lah"
      }
   }
}
}
```

**Notice** how I create a derived type that is the length of string to be written:

```
len     = strlen(x);
status  = H5Tset_size(type, len);
```

---

The HDF5 group does have an [example](http://www.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/examples/misc-examples/attrvstr.c) of writing variable length attributes.